# how to print user1 from user1@10.129.12.121 using shell scripting or sed

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I wanted to print the name from the entire address by shell scripting. So user1@12.12.23.234 should give output "user1" and similarly 11234@12.123.12.23 should give output 11234

Answer (score 5):

Reading from the terminal:

`$ IFS=@ read user host && echo "$user"
<user1@12.12.23.234>
user1`

Reading from a variable:

```
$ address='user1@12.12.23.234'
$ cut -d@ -f1 <<< "$address"
user1
$ sed 's/@.*//' <<< "$address"
user1
$ awk -F@ '{print $1}' <<< "$address"
user1
```

Comment: Your first solution is very interesting! It's a very creative way to process the input quickly while reading from the standard input! +1

Answer (score 4):

Using bash in place editing:

```
EMAIL='user@server.com'
echo "${EMAIL%@*}
```

This is a Bash built-in, so it might not be very portable (it won't run with `sh` if it's not linked to `/bin/bash` for example), but it is probably faster since it doesn't fork a process to handle the editing.

Using sed:

```
echo "$EMAIL" | sed -e 's/@.*//'
```

This tells sed to replace the `@` character and as many characters that it can find after it up to the end of line with nothing, ie. removing everything after the `@`.

This option is probably better if you have multiple emails stored in a file, then you can do something like

```
sed -e 's/@.*//' emails.txt > users.txt
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `expr` for this kind of thing:

```
address='user1@12.12.23.234'
expr "$address" : '\([^@]*\)'
```

This is a use of `expr` for its pattern matching and extraction abilities. Translated, the above says: Please print out the longest prefix of `$address` that doesn't contain an `@`.

The `expr` tool is covered by Posix, so this should be pretty portable.

As a note, some historical versions of `expr` will interpret an argument with a leading `-` as an option. If you care about guarding against that, you can add an extra letter to the beginning of the string, and just avoid matching it, like so:

```
expr "x$address" : 'x\([^@]*\)'
```